# Passing arbitrary object to ThreadContext.put() in Log4j

Tags: java, log4j, mdc

I want to pass an arbitrary object to the `ThreadContext.put()` method like this:

```java
MyObject originalMessage = new MyObject(...);
ThreadContext.put("originalMessage", originalMessage);
```

But that method only allows `String` as its second argument: [docs here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/ThreadContext.html).

Is there a way to put an arbitrary object in log4j in Log4j's MDC? Or an alternative to this? What I want is to allow further executions of `log.error()` to automatically log the `originalMessage` without need of passing it as a parameter everywhere.

Also, I can't invoke `toString()` myself as I would be eagerly evaluating that method (which is quite heavy in this object), so I want its invocation to be delayed until it's needed, just like when you pass an arbitrary object to `log.debug("{}", someObject)`.

Comment: You can searlialize the object as e.g. json or create a `Map<String,Object>` save the object there and put the key in the `ThreadContext`.

Comment: Could you explain more? The `put` method in `ThreadContext` only accepts strings, so if I use a JsonObject or a Map, I still need to convert it to String before being able to put it in the ThreadContext. Docs here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/ThreadContext.html

Comment: You can convert some objects to a string using json and undo this process.

Comment: The main issue is converting this object to string is too heavy, be it with toString or if I first convert it to a JsonObject and then invoke toString in that. In my case, this object is some MB in size and this method is being executed many times.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a (hack) solution [here](http://apache-logging.6191.n7.nabble.com/Non-String-values-in-Thread-Context-Map-MDC-td76812.html#a76817) and [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1648).

Instead of this (which doesn't compile):

```java
ThreadContext.put("originalMessage", originalMessage);
```

I can do:

```java
final var threadContextMap = (ObjectThreadContextMap) ThreadContext.getThreadContextMap();
threadContextMap.putValue("originalMessage", originalMessage);
```

This works as long as you add this JVM option:

```
-Dlog4j2.threadContextMap=org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.CopyOnWriteSortedArrayThreadContextMap
```

Now, this looks hacky because [getThreadContextMap()](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/ThreadContext.html#getThreadContextMap--) the method is supposed to return a read-only view of the internal map:

> Returns a read-only view of the internal data structure used to store thread context key-value pairs ...

So this solution is casting that read-only map and, knowing the implementation is not read-only, modifying it ... not the most transparent solution but it works.